# pull all commits since the shallow clone date or hash

Tags: git, github, version-control

I made a shallow clone from my git repo using `git clone --depth 1 repo_url`. Now, there are few commits in remote after local head and 2-3 new commits in local which are not pushed to remote. When I tried to push my commits to remote, it asks me to pull first. `git pull` command pulls all previous commits(those are done before my shallow clone) to local. But I only need commits done after my shallow clone head and I need all commits since then to avoid conflicts. `git pull --depth n` will only clone the last n commits, but yes, the repo will be updated with latest source after doing a merge commit. But I don't know how many commits are there since my shallow clone. Please let me know some solution for this issue.

Comment: `depth` is available for the `fetch` command, have you tried it?

Comment: yes. I did. But I don't know how many commits are there to specify the depth. So I need all commits pushed after the commit in my shallow clone commit.